# WinForms DataGridView cell edit end event getting the cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to make a cellEditEnd event method, in which I need the cell, that was edited. I could use the selectedCell function, but I would like to know how if there is a way to get the cell object inside the method.

Comment: Does the CellEndEdit event not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the CellEndEdit event : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit(v=vs.110).aspx

Which takes a DataGridViewCellEventArgs as a parameter, this should provide you with the Row and Column index of the cell you need.